# Does Netty provide reliable-ordered UDP messaging?

Tags: udp, netty

Does anyone know if Netty provides reliable messaging (acks) and sequence ordering for UPD messages?  I am looking for a Java messaging library that will allow me to write a game server but provide that functionality so that I don't have to write it.

Comment: TCP? Why search for a reimplementation of all it´s features? Simply broadcasting/multicasting is impossible anyways, because with your requirements, you´ll have to treat every peer separately even if you make a broadcast (at least you´ve to remember which ACKs you´ve received so far etc.)

Comment: No - I do not want to use TCP.  I am following the recommendations in this guide:

http://trac.bookofhook.com/bookofhook/trac.cgi/wiki/IntroductionToMultiplayerGameProgramming

Comment: Which guide? And, sorry to say that, *wanting* to "reimplement" TCP nowadays on a major OS is plain stupid (no, i´m NOT saying "you are stupid")

Comment: I added the guide in my first comment after pressing enter - sorry about that...still getting used to using this post's UI - it seems that one has to press shift-enter to go to the next line...:).  The guide warns to stay away from TCP when writing game servers.  And my question is if Netty provides the optional reliable delivery with ACKs and sequence ordering, so that I can use that when needed instead of trying to use TCP.  Hence, if there is a library that does this, I won't have to reimplement it will I?

Comment: I believe even with optional reliable delivery and sequence ordering, UDP will be much faster still, so when you write a game server, it is worth the trouble of doing this.

Comment: Well...of course you can tailor it to your program needs and can end up faster than a generic TCP implementation. But don´t expect too much difference in 2014. About Netty: Isn´t that a Java lib? Until now I thought of C++ (I´m sure I came from the C++ question page). (If you´re concerned about TCP/UDP difference...Java?)

Comment: Yes...Netty is a Java library, but I found UDP examples out there. So, apparently it handles UDP as well. I'll be reading more about it in the next few days but wanted to see if anyone out there may know of the question to my answer and if Netty does/does not offer reliability and sequence ordering. I was also hoping that perhaps someone out there  might know of another Java library that does this, if Netty does not.  I thought about writing the server in C++, but I prefer not to, I am good at C++, but I am very good at Java, and I have written tons of multi-threaded back end server code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK - I found the answer.  It does!  It provides UDT via these packages:

```
io.netty.channel.udt
io.netty.channel.udt.nio
```

Which include these classes:

```
UdtChannel
UdtChannelConfig
UdtChannelOption
UdtMessage
UdtServerChannel
UdtServerChannelConfig
```

and these ones:

```
NioUdtAcceptorChannel
NioUdtByteAcceptorChannel
NioUdtByteConnectorChannel
NioUdtByteRendezvousChannel
NioUdtMessageAcceptorChannel
NioUdtMessageConnectorChannel
NioUdtMessageRendezvousChannel
NioUdtProvider
```

And it also provides plain UDP via these classes:

```
DatagramChannel
DatagramChannelConfig
DatagramPacket
```